# Pascal's law and pressure gradient

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics

Pascal's law states that *pressure applied on an ideal liquid is equally distributed*.

- Then why is there a pressure gradient in a liquid body? Please let me know what is wrong in what I stated.
- What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pascal's law refers specifically to *hydrostatic* pressure, that is the pressure in a point in the fluid, caused by the *weight* of the fluid column above that point.

Suppose the atmospheric pressure is $p_0$, the fluid's density is $\rho$ and the depth of the point (distance from the fluid's surface) is $h$, then the weight $W$ of the column is:

$$W=\rho g hA,$$

with $A$ the cross-section of the column. Since as pressure is defined as force per unir of area, then:

$$p=p_0+\frac{W}{A}=p_0+\rho gh$$

So Pascal's Law says that in a static fluid, pressure depends only on pressure above the fluid ($p_0$) and the depth.

But:

> Pascal's law states that pressure applied on an ideal liquid is equally distributed.

Is not really what it says. All points of equal distance from the surface will be at the same pressure though.